# LINQ with 2 WHERE condition

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

this is the database table

```
[Table("Score")]
public class Score
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ScoreId { get; set; }
    public int QuizId { get; set; }
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public virtual Quiz Quiz { get; set; }
}
```

i want to return a result of how many record exist on database with this code

```
var query = (from n in db.Scores
where n.PersonId == x && n.Quizid == y                      
select n).Count();
```

x and y have a value.

how i can make this code work with 2 conditions?
or any other way to make this work

Comment: Yeah, that looks like valid LINQ for what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've got should work. A more concise way of writing it would be:

```
db.Scores.Count(n => n.PersonId == x && n.QuizId == y);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem, in terms of compilation, is that `Quizid` does not exist, it's `QuizId`.

Comment: Good catch.  Completely missed that.